# Net snmp build issues

Tags: c++, net-snmp

I'm trying to get some fairly old SNMP code built on windows as I need to make some changes. It compiles fine on UNIX. I've installed net-snmp 5.6.1.1 (the latest according to here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/5.7.2/). However I get a link error due to the source referring to an init_usm() function which is not being exported to the netsnmp.dll. I'd imagine this previously worked.

Does anyone know if this function has been removed from the SNMP library and if so if an alternative exists?

Comment: It definitely hasn't been removed.

Comment: The netsnmp.dll I got from the package above doesn't include this function. It does have an init_usm_conf() however.